# Removing Windows wireless policy GPO settings

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I've configured a group policy to push out wireless settings and set a whitelist for networks - I now need to remove this, however I can't for life of me figure out how.

Current state of the GPO:
Computer > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Wireless Network (802.11) policies
Vista onwards profile

General tab:
Use Windows VLAN AutoConfig service for clients: enabled.
2 Networks defined with certs/ settings etc.

Network Permissions Tab:
One network defined as allow.
Allow users to view denied networks: enabled.

Problem: These setting persist is I unlink the GPO, disable it's settings (both confirmed no longer applied via gpresult), attempting to remove them from the win10 host via registry results in not being able to detect or connect to any wireless networks, leaving the domain and resetting GP had the same result.

What has worked: Re-imaging PC which isn't scalable with the number of hosts that need fixing and adding a entry for each wireless network which again isn't scalable

What I need: A way to allow these hosts to connect to any wireless network

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is still relevant for you, but I just stumbled upon this thread, looking for basically the same issue.

We had configured a group policy blocking all except a single Wireless SSID.
After Removing a Computer from the AD we were facing the issue that the Computer isn't able to connect to any of the other SSIDs.

Turns out the solution lies in wlan filters, which can be configured via netsh:

List configured filters:

```
C:\>netsh wlan show filters

Allow list on the system (group policy)
---------------------------------------
    <None>

Allow list on the system (user)
-------------------------------
    SSID: "mygreatssid", Type: Infrastructure

Block list on the system (group policy)
---------------------------------------
    <None>

Block list on the system (user)
-------------------------------
    SSID: "", Type: Infrastructure
    SSID: "", Type: Ad-hoc
```

(this is what it looked like for us)

To remove the "Allow"-Filter:

```
C:\>netsh wlan delete filter allow mygreatssid infrastructure
```

To remove specific "Block"-Filters (not needed in our case):

```
C:\>netsh wlan delete filter allow mygreatssid infrastructure
```

To remove the "Deny-All"-Filters (those with empty SSID):

```
C:\>netsh wlan delete filter denyall infrastructure
C:\>netsh wlan delete filter denyall adhoc
```

The full help for the delete filter command is available via:

```
C:\>netsh wlan delete filter help
```

To *add* a (new) filter, just replace `delete` with `add`

If you configured the policy to not allow users to view denied networks, you can set this via netsh too (default seems to be "hide"):

```
C:\>netsh wlan set blockednetworks <show|hide>
```

Comment: Depending on GPO, its sometimes impossible to remove filter. instead try deleting C:\Windows\wlansvc\Policies\Pol****.tmp